# When is the ros::shutdown() called for this test_localization_node_bag_pose_tester.cpp of ROS robot_localization package?

Tags: unit-testing, c++11, localization, ros, googletest

How and when does this [while loop](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/0d3c7cc76461eaee77593c95b390a3a7897e30e2/test/test_localization_node_bag_pose_tester.cpp#L70) exit happen in the context of this [rostest](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/noetic-devel/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag2.test) ?

Answer (score 0):

It exits when **ros::ok()** returns **false**

This link explains **ros::ok()** behaviour:https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)

> ros::ok() will return false if:
>
> - a SIGINT is received (Ctrl-C)
> - we have been kicked off the network by another node with the same name
> - ros::shutdown() has been called by another part of the application.

Also test could have timeout defined in [test_ekf_localization_node_bag2.test](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/0d3c7cc76461eaee77593c95b390a3a7897e30e2/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag2.test#L76) `time-limit="1000.0"` but I guess it would bypass ros::ok() and kill the node before finishing (you could always test it by modifying timeout)

So in your case I assume you would launch test node, wait until bagfile is finished and exit by Ctrl+C. Unless it exits by itself at the end